# How can I add the most recent line item in a group by with aggregates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Hey stackoverflow community,

I have a table of `Sales`, hypothetical shown below.

```
Customer       Revenue       State      Date
David          $100          NY         2016-01-01
David          $500          NJ         2016-01-03
Fred           $200          CA         2016-01-01
Fred           $200          CA         2016-01-02
```

I'm writing a simple query of revenue generated by customer. The output returns as such:

```
David     $600
Fred      $400
```

What I want to do now is add the row for the latest purchase date along with the state associated with the latest purchase.

Desired result:

```
David     $600      2016-01-03        NJ
Fred      $400      2016-01-02        CA
```

I would like to keep the SQL code as clean as possible. I also want to avoid doing a JOIN to a new query as this query can start to get complex. Any ideas as to how to do so?

Comment: what if a customer has 2 transactions in different states on the same latest date?

Comment: @vkp sorry, my actual use case will be unique timestamps, more granular than dates. so in the case when `Dave` purchases two items at the same time, he will always purchase them from the same location.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `row_number()` (or `first_value()`) and conditional aggregation:

```
select customer, sum(revenue), max(date),
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then state end) as mostRecentState
from (select s.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customer order by date desc) as seqnum
      from s
     ) s
group by customer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hy, try this:

```
SELECT
   S.CUSTOMER
  ,S.TOTAL
  ,M.DT
  ,M.STATE
FROM
(
  --SUM
  SELECT
     CUSTOMER
    ,SUM(REVENUE) AS TOTAL
  FROM TB
  GROUP BY
    CUSTOMER
) S 
INNER JOIN (
        --MAX DATE
        SELECT
          CUSTOMER
          ,STATE
          ,DT
       FROM TB
       WHERE (CUSTOMER, DT) IN (
                              SELECT AUX.CUSTOMER ,MAX(AUX.DT)  
                              FROM TB AUX 
                              GROUP BY AUX.CUSTOMER
                            )
) M ON (S.CUSTOMER = M.CUSTOMER );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Customer
  , (SELECT SUM(Revenue) FROM #t WHERE Customer = xx.Customer ) AS TotalRevenue
  , Dt, STATE
FROM #t xx
WHERE Dt = (SELECT MAX(Dt) FROM #t WHERE Customer = xx.Customer)
ORDER BY Customer
```

Answer (score 0):

On large data sets, I would avoid using the `ROW_NUMBER()` function due to performance issues. Here is a sample of how I've done this in the past with good performance results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t.customer,
    totals.totalRevenue,
    t.state,
    t.date
FROM
    @test AS t INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            customer,
            SUM(revenue) AS totalRevenue,
            MAX(date) AS maxDate
        FROM
            @test AS tSub
        GROUP BY
            customer
    ) AS totals ON t.customer = totals.customer AND t.date = totals.maxDate
```

If the customer and date fields are unique per record, you can remove the `DISTINCT` clause at the top.

Try  `SET STATISTICS IO ON` and `SET STATISTICS TIME ON` before executing your query--less logical disk IO generally means better performance.